# Updating a JSON file with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to update JSON file  with a single value.  The file is updated but is getting updated with a bunch of extra data that I don't want or need.

Here is a snippet from the PowerShell script:

Id.txt contains one string "16963e76"

```
$outPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent\pipelines\mypipeline\Application\Application\Id.txt"
$imageid = Get-Content $outPath
$filejson = Get-Content -Raw -Path $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json
$filejson.parameters.Image = $imageid
$filejson | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $filepath -Encoding utf8 -Force
```

Here is what I expect my JSON to look like:

```
{
  "name": "perf-a",
  "cft_file":"cft/cft.json",
  "parameters": {
    "AppEnvironmentType": "perf",
    "Image": "16963e76"
  },
  "tags": {
    "Owner": "email@me.com",
    "CostCenter": "12345"
  }
}
```

Here is what my JSON actually looks like after the update:

```
{
    "name":  "perf-a",
    "cft_file":  "cft/cft.json",
    "parameters":  {
        "AppEnvironmentType":  "perf",
        "Image":  {
            "value":  "16963e76",
            "PSPath":  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Go Agent\\pipelines\\mypipeline\\Application\\Application\\Id.txt",
            "PSParentPath":  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Go Agent\\pipelines\\mypipeline\\Application\\Application",
            "PSChildName":  "Id.txt",
            "PSDrive":  "C",
            "PSProvider":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem",
            "ReadCount":  1
        }
    },
    "tags":  {
        "Owner":  "email@me.com",
        "CostCenter":  "12345"
    }
}
```

What is causing this issue and how can I stop it from happening?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: OK so when you import the string from id.txt powershell is adding several noteproperties from the environment, usually these don't matter and can be ignored.  However ConvertTo-JSON is extracting these note properties from the object and inserting them into your json.

By using the tostring method my solution works by changing what was a string into another string, but this time without the note properties, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

added correct reason for solution working.

OK so when you import the string from id.txt powershell is adding several noteproperties from the environment, usually these don't matter and can be ignored.

However ConvertTo-JSON is extracting these note properties from the object and inserting them into your json. By using the tostring method my solution works by changing what was a string into another string, but this time without the note properties, so it works.

```
$outPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent\pipelines\mypipeline\Application\Application\Id.txt"
$imageid = (Get-Content $outPath).ToString()
$filejson = Get-Content -Raw -Path $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json
$filejson.parameters.Image = $imageid
$filejson | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $filepath -Encoding utf8 -Force
```

PREVIOUS INCORRECT REASON:

The $imageid is actually an object when you import it like that and the convertto-json is putting the full object into your file.

You should make sure that $imageid is just a string and whilst there are a few ways of doing this you could use the tostring method as below.

Answer (score 0):

Probably change this:

```
`$filejson.parameters.Image = $imageid.value`
```

Because you are passing an object to the `$filejson.parameters.Image`, but you only need 1 property of that object.

Comment: `$imageid` is a `[string]` instance (due to having been assigned the output from `Get-Content` applied to a single-line input file), so it doesn't have a `.value` property (it _is_ decorated with note properties added by PS, however, as Jim's answer explains).

Comment: P.S.: The `value` property in the JSON output in the question is an artifact of how `ConvertTo-Json` stringifies value types and strings that are decorated with `NoteProperty` and/or `ScriptProperty` members.